# How can I get Upload Progress with httpClient 4?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here is the download function, I can use listener to get the download progress,How can I
get the upload progress like the download function.Thank you!

```
public void doGetToFile(String url, String localFilePath,CloudStatusListener listener) throws RestHttpException, HttpException {
    final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    final HttpResponse resp;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        BasicCredentialsProvider creds= new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        creds.setCredentials(new AuthScope(CloudClient.CLOUDHOST,CloudClient.CLOUDPORT),new UsernamePasswordCredentials(UserName,Password));
        httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(creds);


        resp = httpClient.execute(request);
        long totalnum=resp.getEntity().getContentLength();
        if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath);

            InputStream inputStream=resp.getEntity().getContent();

            long bytesRead=0;
            int bufferSize=listener.progressInterval();
            byte b[]=new byte[bufferSize];

            int cnt=0;
            while((cnt=inputStream.read(b))!=-1)
            {
                out.write(b,0,cnt);
                bytesRead+=cnt;
                listener.onProgress(bytesRead, totalnum);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            //resp.getEntity().writeTo(out);

            out.close();
            return;
        } else {
            final String response = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            throw new RestHttpException(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), response);
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new HttpException("IOException " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem, you can do it like this:

```
class FileBodyCounter extends FileBody {
    private volatile long byteCount;
    private volatile CloudStatusListener listener;
    private volatile long totalnum;

    public FileBodyCounter(File file,CloudStatusListener listener,long totalnum) {
        super(file);
        this.listener=listener;
        this.totalnum=totalnum;
    }

    public long getBytesWritten() {
        return byteCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super.writeTo(new FilterOutputStream(out) {
            //
            // Other write() methods omitted for brevity. 
            // Implement for better performance
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                 byteCount++;
                 super.write(b);
                 if (byteCount % listener.progressInterval() == 0 ||
                    byteCount == totalnum){
                    listener.onProgress(byteCount,totalnum);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The post function is like this:

```
public String doPostMultipart(String url, 
                                String filePath, 
                                List<NameValuePair> params,
                                CloudStatusListener listener
                                ) 
                                throws RestHttpException, 
                                        HttpException, 
                                        IOException {

    if (params == null) params = EMPTY_PARAMS;

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);


    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    if (filePath != null && !filePath.isEmpty()) {
        FileBody bin = new FileBodyCounter(
                                    new File(filePath),
                                    listener,
                                    new FileInputStream(
                                        new File(filePath)
                                        ).available());
        reqEntity.addPart("fileUpload", bin);
    }

    for (NameValuePair kv : params) {
        multipartAddKV(reqEntity, kv.getName(), kv.getValue());
    }

    request.setEntity(reqEntity);

    return execute(request);
}
```